# Why is mysql database information won't pass to express.js function?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, asynchronous

I have this code

```
app.get("/api/tables", function(req, res) {

    function retrieve() {
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM reservations", function(err, res) {
            if (err) throw err;
            return res;
        });
    }

    res = retrieve();
    console.log(res,"results");

    return res;
});
```

It selects everything from the table, then I set a res for express.js function to be equal to that function, but it comes out undefined.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

These node.js operations are *asynchronous*, but you're treating them as synchronous. Your `retrieve()` function `return`s to its caller before the query runs, and before the callback function runs.

You need something like this:

```
app.get("/api/tables", function(req, res) {
    function retrieve(){
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM reservations", function(err, resultset) {
            if (err) {
                console.log (err);
                res.status(500).send('query error')l
            }
            else {
                console.log (resultset);
                res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(resultset);
            }
        });
     }
     retrieve();
}
```

The point is to send the result of the query back to the requesting client *from inside the callback.*